# Windows Package Manger upgrade Python 3

Tags: python, windows-package-manager

I want to upgrade my Python 3 install to a specific version of python 3 (3.8.10), but I can't figure out the complete version that "windows package manager" is expecting.

`winget upgrade --id Python.Python.3 --version 3.8.10` says "No version found matching 3.8.10"

My current version is 3.6.8150.0. What is the 8150 number? I can't find documentation of that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The number you see and the number you should be passing to `--version` is the version of the winget package, not of Python itself.

I am not clear on why all the Python winget packages have `150` in their package version (the contribution docs don't seem to be enforcing a consistent versioning scheme). But looking at the available options at [winget-pkgs](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs), the one you want is likely `3.8.10150.0`.